# Button swapped using AJAX results in ignored listener for new button

Tags: jquery

I use AJAX to call a PHP script and replace some HTML with the results data so a user can confirm the data.  The initial button is "Fetch Data" and then I swap that out with 2 new buttons "Confirm Data" and "Try Again" (in case the user doesn't want to validate the script result.

HTML button being replaced:

```
<div class="btn-container" id="btn-container">
        <button type="button" id="fetch_btn" value="fetch_it" class="btn-btn btn btn-dark border-light center-button mt-2">
                <div class="btn-text">
                    Fetch Data
                </div>
        </button>
</div>
```

Ajax works just fine:

```
   $("#new_case_form").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var county_name = $("#county_select").val();
      var case_number = $("#case_num").val();
      // console.log($("#county_select").val());
      var the_url = "fetch_case.php?county="+county_name+"&case_number="+case_number;
      var response = $.ajax({
          url: the_url,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(data){
              $("#case-confirm").html(data);
              $("#btn-container").html("<button type=\"button\" name=\"confirm_btn\" id=\"confirm_btn\" value=\"confirm\" class=\"btn-btn btn btn-dark border-light center-button mt-2\"><div class=\"btn-text\" id=\"confirm_btn_text\">Confirm Case</div></button><button type=\"button\" name=\"try_again\" id=\"try_again_btn\" value=\"try again\" class=\"btn-btn btn btn-dark border-light center-button mt-2\"><div class=\"btn-text\" id=\"try_again_btn_text\">Try Again</div></button>");
          }
      });
  });
```

Here is the new HTML in a more readable format:

```
<button type="button" name="confirm_btn" id="confirm_btn" value="confirm" class="btn-btn btn btn-dark border-light center-button mt-2">
    <div class="btn-text" id="confirm_btn_text">
        Confirm Case
    </div>
</button>
<button type="button" name="try_again" id="try_again_btn" value="try again" class="btn-btn btn btn-dark border-light center-button mt-2">
    <div class="btn-text" id="try_again_btn_text">
        Try Again
    </div>
</button>
```

This is the jQuery I use in trying to do anything with the Try Again button once it's clicked:

```
  $("#try_again_btn").click(function(e){
      console.log('confirm btn clicked');
  });
```

I have also tried

```
  $("#try_again_btn").on("click",function(e){
      console.log('confirm btn clicked');
  });
```

I have also used #try_again_btn_text because I nested an HTML tag inside the `<button>` and thought maybe when the text is clicked it doesn't fire the trigger on the parent `button` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try `$("#btn-container").on("click", "#try_again_btn", function(e){...}`

Comment: It doesn't trigger because your javascript works before you add that element to your document. Look at jQuery's on() function. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I just finished reading the link provided above.  Seems like it should work.  I'll check it out and post results back to provide closure here if it does in deed work.  I had no idea to even search for the term "event binding"

Comment: Wow.  Such a simple little solution, but without the link to the other question, I don't think I would have found it.  Nurdyguy, you might not be able to answer a "duplicate" but if you can, I'll select yours as the answer because it worked.

Comment: Yes nurdyguy solution works because you need to make a *delegated* event handler (because your element is created after the call to on()). And to do that you need to pass a selector as a second argument

Comment: Thanks Benoit, that's what I read at the link posted above.